# Troubleshooting IIS web package deployment with SQL database

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a .NET MVC project that gets its data from a SQL database.

When I run the project in debug mode on my local machine, it runs without error; however, after I deploy the project to my IIS server (version 6 I believe) using Microsoft's Publish Wizard (create a .zip, move that .zip to the wwwRoot folder the website is pointed at), I encounter an issue: I access the website's main page via URL address, but when I enter the login ID, it produces a built-in error message "Invalid user ID".

The only time this error ever occurs when a valid ID is entered is if the database cannot be reached to check login credentials. So, using SQL Profiler, I tried to see if a query was made to the database - it appears that the answer is "no".

I have verified that the connection strings are configured correctly in the IIS environment, and can safely assume that there are no code-related errors with regards to this issue.

The question:  What other troubleshooting methods are available for IIS and SQL interactions to see what the root of this error is, or what suggestions might you have to try and eliminate the problem

Comment: Application events on IIS server. Is the firewall on? Are they on the same domain? Can IIS server actually 'see' sql server? Furthermore, you may need to log failed/successful login attempts. By default, SQL server doesn't log those failed attempts.

Comment: The Event Logs on the IIS server (which is the same machine that hosts the SQL server) gives an error saying "Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\OPOC'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database".    I am certain that these are in the same domain, as this IIS server has been running the test environment for this project for some time. Whether or not it can see the SQL server, I'm not sure how to confirm that, but I had assumed so since it was working before I re-deployed the application after some changes to a few Views

Comment: I've checked in the Security folder for the SQL server, and it has APPPOOL\OPOC added to the Login list, so I don't think the AppPool I'm using is the issue, but I'm completely new to IIS deployment, more or less, so I could be wrong

Comment: Add the user to the database logins and grant this user access to the database. Connection string in your code should have its credentials. Reason why it works on your machine is likely because you are sysadmin or something on the server. Look up a way to enter credentials in your connection string's parameters.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sp6lR15iWMk

Comment: Well, I don't understand why, but for whatever reason that seems to have fixed my test environment server. I'll have to check out the production server as well and see what that's set to. Cheers for now!

Comment: Glad I could help. The reasoning behind it is that the service that requires access to the database needs to be granted access. Embedded within the request, the actual credentials you want to use (or personify) are there. Like... to get to be able to knock on the door, you need to be granted access to that. Then, to open the door and do stuff in there, you need access for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the user to the database logins and grant this user access to the database. Connection string in your code should have its credentials. Reason why it works on your machine is likely because you are sysadmin or something on the server. Look up a way to enter credentials in your connection string's parameters.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sp6lR15iWMk

Comment: Another thing I found after looking at the production server - it has the Identity for the AppPool set to NetworkService. I did this to the test environment and it works just as well. I assume that the "NetworkService" Identity grants permissions to anyone who has valid network access to that server?

Comment: Uhm.. Stay clear of `NetworkService` in a domain controlled environment. Highly recommended to create a service account at the domain level.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the warning! As it's not a terribly critical application, I'm assuming my predecessor who originally created all this was just doing the "whatever would make it work" method he seemed to like to employ quite often. Would setting the Identity to LocalSystem still allow for all computers in the domain to access the application (as long as they are allowed to according to domain privileges) or do they need to be of an elevated status on the host box specifically? Still sorting this out in my head but you're giving better info than anyone else could so I thought I'd ask.

Comment: LocalSystem does not grant you access to anything outside of the box. It's great for sandbox environment (no networked drive or anything). If you are keen to learn, I encourage you to lookup [SQL books online](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130214(v=sql.105).aspx)